# Permission Denied in order to load Image from Android Internal Storage

Tags: java, android

Started learning java and app development. I tried to display a single Picture with a hard-coded path. I got left with an Error telling me, that the necessary permissions are missing:

***Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/media/logo.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)***

***AndroidManifest.xml*:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.snwflake22.helloworld" >
    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
    (...)
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The function itself looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    File image = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/media/", "logo.jpg");
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Are there any other permissions I need to set to access the storage? or the media folder?

Comment: Also you haven't used `setContentView` in your `onCreate`. Not related to the permission error but you need to fix that before it'll work.

Comment: @MatterCat it might be a service or a fragment

Comment: If they're just starting out, it's most likely that it's an Activity. I suppose that's fair, though.

Comment: @MatterCat hmmm yup true, but we should focus on his error, the permission error.

Comment: it is indeed a service, i may just started out with java, but i am familiar with service based architecture in software development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use small caps on ANDROID.PERMISSION

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: that solved it for me, thanks. the completion of android studio made it fully upper case...