# Android studio unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android-studio

hello i'm trying to save pictures taken from url on my application, but when i try to access the memory to place the data, an error comes out

unable to decode stream java.io.FileNotFoundException /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Messenger/20180117_113943.jpg (Permission denied)

i want to select picture to my application.

This is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
protected static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 111;
protected static final int SELECT_FILE = 222;
private Bitmap m_bitmap1;

Global mGlobal;
AdView adView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);



    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    //Locate the Banner Ad in activity_main.xml
    adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.ads);

    // Request for Ads
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()

            .build();

    // Load ads into Banner Ads
    try {
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    mGlobal = ((Global) getApplication());

    findViewById(R.id.camera).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File f = new File(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(f));
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);

        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.galery).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
                    SELECT_FILE);
        }
    });


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // /==========================

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SelectcropActivity.class);


        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .toString());
            for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                    f = temp;
                    break;
                }
            }
            try {
                BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                btmapOptions.inSampleSize = 2;

                m_bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                        btmapOptions);

                mGlobal.setImage(m_bitmap1);

                startActivity(i);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        } else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String tempPath = getPath(selectedImageUri,
                    MainActivity.this);
            BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            Bitmap bm1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempPath, btmapOptions);

            Matrix mat = new Matrix();
            Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm1, 0, 0,
                    bm1.getWidth(), bm1.getHeight(), mat, true);
            mGlobal.setImage(bMapRotate);
            startActivity(i);


        }

    }
}





public String getPath(Uri uri, Activity activity) {
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = activity
            .managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}}
```

This is logout :

```
01-27 19:07:08.609 20624-20624/com.ideanet.animalfacemorph E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Messenger/20180117_113943.jpg (Permission denied)
01-27 19:07:08.611 20624-20624/com.ideanet.animalfacemorph D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-27 19:07:08.612 20624-20624/com.ideanet.animalfacemorph E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=222, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/9528 flg=0x1 launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } (has extras) }} to activity {com.ideanet.animalfacemorph/com.ideanet.animalfacemorph.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: It says ` (Permission denied)`. Have you tried running it with higher privileges?

Comment: @Gab Can you please explain more my app worked perfect on the emulator Genymotion (Galaxy S4) but when i tested it on my Galaxy S8 it gave me that error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permission Denied in order to load Image from Android Internal Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529908/permission-denied-in-order-to-load-image-from-android-internal-storage)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file the following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```